# How to refer to object from other keyframe

Tags: flash, reference, actionscript-2, root, keyframe

I want to get information of an object from a previous keyframe.
_root. works only for objects on the same keyframe as the code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object doesn't exist one you leave the keyframe that created it, unless the object was added with ActionScript. You'll have the place the object on its own layer and extend the keyframe to reach the point where you're trying to access it, or as mentioned create it with ActionScript.

[image]