# How to access/set dynamic text box which is in defferent keyframe in external swf file in flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a external swf file which has a dynamic text field in key-frame 70 how can i set that field's text from another fla project.

I tried like

```
ldr = new Loader();
rq = new URLRequest("extarnal.swf");
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ExLoaded); 
ldr.load(rq);

function ExLoaded(e:Event):void 

{                   
    var externalSWF:MovieClip= MovieClip(e.currentTarget.content);
    externalSWF.ThatDynamicText.text="this is a test";  // got error here 
    addChild(externalSWF);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a layer for the dynamic text field and expand the layer 70 frames. related post: [How to refer to object from other keyframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8934346/1696720)

If using `TLF` text in external swf file check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18373832/1696720).